# How could Darth Vader be a Transformer?

Tags: star-wars, transformers

While following my kids in the toys aisle of a big department store, I spotted a strange crossover : Star Wars and Transformers :

[image: STAR WARS TRANSFORMERS DARTH VADER to STAR DESTROYER]

How could it possibly happen? The Transformers's home world wasn't supposed to be in our galaxy, or at least contemporary, and Star Wars "*A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away....*"?

Is there any explanation on how the 2 universes could merge or it is just a thoughtless commercial combination?

Comment: I'm voting thoughtless commercial combination.

Comment: Darth Vader is a transformer spy sent through a time machine to combat Santa Claus from an alternate universe where Superman had an artificially concieved child with a Puppeteer.

Comment: The day we treat the toy aisles as canon is the day I turn in my geek card.

Comment: @Gilles You of course mean [Robot Santa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_recurring_characters_in_Futurama#Robot_Santa).

Comment: [Merchandising! Merchandising! That's where the real money from the movie is made](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/quotes)!

Comment: Actually, that is just [the start of the weirdness](http://www.seibertron.com/transformers/toys/series/marvel/47/)!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Taking the second question first:

> Is there any explanation on how the 2 universes could merge or it is
>   just a thoughtless commercial combination?

For the most part, yes, [in 2008 Hasbro launched the Transformers Crossovers line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_%28toy_line%29#Transformers%3a_Crossovers_.282008.29); this was purely for commercial gain, and it was never done with any intent of defining canon.

Now taking the first question:

> How could it possibly happen?

[Parallel/alternate universes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_universe_%28fiction%29) and bridges between them are always a good explanation for these types of things.

Depending on which representation of the Transformers you are referring to (there are [a number of different representations of the Transformers in media](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_%28disambiguation%29)), there is support for the idea that alternate universes do exist in many versions of the Transformers universes:

- In [Generation One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_%28comics%29#The_Transformers_.28Generation_1.29.2C_Marvel.2C_U.S.) (the first appearance of the Transformers in comic form in the US), Spider-Man appears in issue three, implying that the Transformers exist in [Earth-616](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-616)<sup>1</sup>, which is one in many alternate realities (which are able to be bridged, as the [Exiles did regularly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exiles_%28Marvel_Comics%29), as it was their mission to protect the Multiverse) within the [Marvel Multiverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_%28Marvel_Comics%29).
- In October of 2007, Marvel and IDW published a [New Avengers/Transformers crossover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Avengers/Transformers) which did not take place outside of Earth-616 (again, existing in the Marvel Mutliverse).
- ["Infestation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infestation_%28IDW_Publishing%29) was a [mega-crossover event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_crossover) among all of IDW's major titles, [including the Transformers series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infestation_%28IDW_Publishing%29#Transformers%3a_Infestation_.231-2).  The core of the event hinged on bridges between alternate universes.
- ["Chaos"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transformers_%28IDW_Publishing%29#Chaos) was released in 2011, and in it, [Galvatron believes](http://nerdynothings.com/comic-reviews/transformers-24/) he is on a righteous path to save Cybertron from an attack launched from the ["Dead Universe"defined as](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Dead_Universe):

> a mysterious and malevolent realm that exists beyond the plane of
>   "normal" space.

That said, it's safe to say that alternate universes *do* exist in the realm of the Transformers universe(s), and it's only through that could that universe and the Star Wars universe collide.

Now whether or not that *actually* did happen or supports this toy's existence is a separate question.

Basically, it could and it's not outside the realm of possibility but not currently supported in canon from either fictional universe.

---

<sup>1</sup> [It is debated whether or not the Marvel comics version of the Transformers existed in Earth-616](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_%28comics%29#Note).  However, the opponents of that idea counter that the Transformers actually existed in [Earth-120185](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-120185#Marvel_UK), which still supports the idea that the Transformers exist within the Marvel Multiverse and subject to exposure from alternate realities.

Comment: I thought parallel universes definitely did exist in the Transformer world. E.g. After G1 was tied in with Beast Wars (so one universe), there was Armada and then the new movies. I thought that the [universe toy line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Universe) was based on this concept, with Unicron pulling characters from different universes.

Comment: There was, in the Marvel comics, an excellent crossover series between the Transformers and GIJoe, which I have around the house somewhere.  But you're right, there are at least half a dozen different Transformers universes defined by marketing, if not more.  With Transformers, it's entirely about marketing, not canon.

Comment: @BBlake The four issue limited series had Spider-Man in it, so it stands to reason that the Transformers (at least in the Marvel comics adaptation) exist on Earth-616.  Additionally, the [Marvel cross-over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_(comics)#G.I._Joe_and_The_Transformers.2C_Marvel.2C_U.S..2C_1986) still dealt with that reality, so if it is Earth-616 (where alternate realities are rampant), then it stands to reason it's more prevalent than I implied.  I've updated the answer, as this fact doesn't change the core fact that it would be an alternate universe.

Comment: @Wikis I'm not sure where G1 was tied with Beast Wars (I didn't follow), but based on BBlake comment, the G1 comic series is set in Earth-616, so it's more prevalent.  I've updated the answer to reflect that without taking away the gist that it would be an alternate universe.

Comment: Come to think of it, the whole story makes more sense when you realize that Anakin Skywalker was simply a Decepticon Pretender all along.

Answer (score 5):

Well, since the Transformers exist contemporaneously with our world, and the "Star Wars" movies exist in our world, perhaps some Transformers happen to be fans and decided to cosplay.

Comment: I like this more as an answer. Occam's Razor at it's finest.